# Rise/Fall time of GP Pins

Tags: avr, clock, rise-time

Are rise/fall times typically affected by the clock speed.  That is if I have a AVR at 16 MHz will it have a different rise/fall time than the same AVR at 32kHz?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually called "drive strength" or "speed" and is configurable in some microcontrollers like STM32 and Altera FPGAs.

In general, the *edge*-rate is not controlled by clock speed.

Edge rate (or slew rate as Ben points out) is controlled by the source impedance of the driver, rather than the oscillation speed. Because edge rates can be *so* much faster than the clock rates, sometimes you want to limit it by changing the internal drive setting or by placing series resistance into the line to reduce RF emissions.

The edge rate has to be fast enough to get to full amplitude during a cycle for a fast clock speed, but otherwise there isn't any real limit on how fast or slow the edge rate is in comparison to the clock rate. Edge rate and clock rate are the result of different physical processes and circuitry.

Comment: Another common term is "slew rate"

Comment: Why is it not controlled by clock speed??

Comment: If the clocks originate from the same xtal and divider chain and logic gates, they will produce the same rise/fall times.

Comment: @Jasser Because, edge rate is not directly related to the cycle time of the clock.

Comment: @Sparky256 That is explicitly wrong.

Comment: @Daniel. It is correct if the final clock outputs are the same logic gates, if the clock is selected by a mux before-hand. Your statement would be true for original clock sources of different type and speeds. PECL would be much faster than CMOS, etc.

Comment: @Sparky256 I read your comment backwards.. apologies. Yeah you're right as long as you don't change any output drive settings, add impedance, etc.

Comment: @Daniel. Thx. PECL dominates motherboards of all sizes, with rise and fall times in the pico-second range...yikes!